# Gmail Email Not Working - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, smtp, mageplaza

I am using magento 2.3.5, But on my website Gmail emails are not working, if i am using gmail for placing order or anything on my website, but i cannot receive email. If i am using any other email that's working fine. Now i have installed this **Mage Plaza SMTP Extension** But now i am getting this error, can you please check why i am getting this error or how to i can fix gmail issue on my website.

[image: mageplaza magento2 smtp]

Extension link: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp#user-guide

Thanks

Comment: please follow this link and check the exception & debug logs once 
https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/configure-gmail-smtp-magento-2.html

Comment: Hey, you can use the test section in the extension, do you receive the email? in the email  logs there is the emails pending? https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/configure-gmail-smtp-magento-2.html check this might help in something. Hope it helps

Comment: i am following same steps  SMTP Provider options is not showing

Comment: please check this option in your gmail account https://prnt.sc/tuzmm8

Comment: 1st i was done this one and then i was installed module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the cronjob? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

It might be helpful for you